# How to show $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{\log(n)}{n} = \gamma \log(2) - \frac{\log^2(2)}{2}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Manipulating the gamma function, I realized that this result is equal to $\eta^{\prime}(1)$, where $\eta(x)$ is the Dirichet's eta function. $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Comment: Here are found some proofs: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h1761372

Comment: The first step is $\zeta(s)-\frac1{s-1} = (s-1) \int_1^\infty (\sum_{n \le x}\frac1n - \log x) x^{-s}dx=(s-1) \int_1^\infty(\gamma+O(x^{-1}))x^{-s}dx=  \gamma+O(\frac{s-1}{s})$. The next step is to find $\eta'(1)$ in term of $f'(1)=\gamma$ where $\eta(s) = (1-2^{1-s}) \zeta(s), f(s) =(s-1)\zeta(s)$